# copy files from master to orphan branch without coping the revisions

Tags: git

I want to push certain stages of my work to github.com, but I do not want to push my master with all those tiny changes and hundreds of commits.

So I thought to create an `orphan` branch *publish* by undertaking the following steps:

```
git checkout --orphan publish
git rm -rf .
```

is there a way to copy certain files or folders from the `master` to `publish`, without copying the revision history?

Comment: Note that in Git, history *is* commits. If you have a chain of commits, you have history. What `--orphan` does is set things up so that the next commit has no parent: it therefore has no history. It still has whatever *files* are in the index, and that's what your `git rm -rf .` is for: to empty out the index, so that the next commit has no files yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, you can checkout files.

```
git checkout master -- example.txt somefolder/somesubfolder
```

This command is telling git to checkout into your working directory the file `example.txt` and the folder `somefolder/somesubfolder` as they are in the branch `master`. This isn't the same as doing a checkout of the `master` branch itself – you stay on your current `HEAD` – and nor is it any kind of merge. It's like copying the file from elsewhere.

Comment: I do this while I'm in the _publishing_ branch?

Comment: Yes, so what's it's doing is telling git to check out into your working directory the file `example.txt` and the folder `somefolder\somesubfolder` as they are in the branch `master`. This isn't the same as doing a checkout of the `master` branch itself - you stay on your current `HEAD` - and nor is it any kind of merge. It's like copying the file from elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, for correctness doesn't it need to be `somefolder/somesubfolder`, `/` instead of `\\` ?

Comment: It'd be `\ ` in `cmd`, but otherwise you're right. I usually use Git bash when I am using Windows, so I'm surprised at myself for using `\ `.